# AMD APP include files missing functions and types available in kernels

Tags: windows, compilation, include, opencl, amd-processor

I'm writing OpenCL code on Windows7 + Cygwin + AMD APP (downloaded a few weeks ago). My code works, but - some of the kernel-accessible functions are missing from the header files, e.g.:

```
void barrier(cl_mem_fence_flags flags)

event_t async_work_group_copy(
    __local gentype *dst,
    const __global gentype *src,
    size_t  num_gentypes,
    event_t event)
```

as well as the `event_t` data type. Like I said, this does not prevent compilation, since the kernels are not compiled by my C compiler but by the OpenCL library. Why is this the case, and what should I do about it?

Comment: As these functions are available only in kernel code, why do you expect to find them in header files used by the host code?  The code is not standard C so the host compiler would not be able to compile code using such a header.

Comment: @chippies: I expect to find them because I find all the rest; and because "pre-compilation" is necessary in the IDE to check syntax and call semantics as best possible; and because function signatures are needed for auto-completion and hinting; etc.

Comment: You may need to download a plugin from AMD for your IDE to properly handle those features for OpenCL kernel code (no guarantee that there is a plugin).  Since you are using AMD APP SDK, you can also edit your kernels in their KernelAnalyzer, which does provide those features.

Comment: @chippies: If they would have a plugin, I'm sure they would have fixed up their headers... there isn't one that I know of. Will look into the KernelAnalyzer - why not make that an answer?

Answer (score 2):

**To summarise:**

The OP was searching for header files that define OpenCL C functions used inside kernels as these header files could be used by IDEs for code highlighting, auto-completion, picking up on syntax errors, etc.  This is not part of the OpenCL standard so the fact that the AMD APP SDK provided some of the functions in header files is just lucky for the OP.

**The answer:**

The correct way to tackle this IDE requirement is either through a purpose-built OpenCL C IDE or through plugins to your favourite IDE.  I don't know of any good plugins, so all that's left are special IDEs.  For AMD GPUs and CPUs, you can use the KernelAnalyzer that comes as part of the AMD APP SDK.  However, this does not work on systems without an AMD GPU (specific .dll is missing).  In such cases, you can try [OpenCL Studio](http://www.opencldev.com/).  Note that this does not work on AMD GPUs due to an incompatibility with Catalyst drivers after 11.9.  Lastly, Notepad++ does have a user defined language file for OpenCL 1.0 (have not tried it though).